# Is there any way to reconnect online without quitting to the menu?

Tags: dark-souls-2

One of my favorite improvements that DSII has over it's predecessor is that it can gracefully transition from online to offline in the case of a disconnect. I haven't found a way to connect back online after a disconnect without backing out to the menu.

Is there a way I can seamlessly transition online after a disconnect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way to reconnect online without quitting to the menu.

Comment: The patch notes for 1.03 do not have any mention of this. Do you have a source? http://www.vg247.com/2014/04/09/dark-souls-2-update-1-03-hits-asia-worldwide-on-friday-patch-notes-inside/

Comment: Sorry I thought this was the online issue ' Failing to create Multiplayer session no longer disables use of online items, such as White Soapstone.' A lot of bugs, got them muddled.